# automatic download of files from a folder on a computer to telegram

Tags: telegram

tell me, is it possible to do something so that the files that are on the local computer, in a folder,  automatically downloaded to Telegram to saved messages?

for example, I put the file in folder 1 and that the file from folder 1 was automatically loaded into telegram to saved messages

Is this possible only through a bot?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)